# Set up .conf file to allow for "wildcard" in URL

Tags: php, nginx

Not sure if this is possible, but what I'm looking to do is have users directed to the exact same directory and file regardless of what particular URL path they come from.

For example, I would like `test.mysite.com/person1` and `test.mysite.com/person2` to come to the same index page.

Some pseudo-code for my .conf (nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80;
   server_name  test.mysite.com/person1; 
   location / {
       root  /home/testing/public_html;
       index index.html; 
     try_files                   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
       port_in_redirect off;
}
```

Can I do something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
   server_name  test.mysite.com/*; //Something here that indicates wildcard
   location / {
       root  /home/testing/public_html;
       index index.html; 
     try_files                   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
       port_in_redirect off;
}
```

The entire point of this is that I'm going to supply "personal" URLs to people that include their name like so: `test.mysite.com/person1`. I'll use javascript to get the unique part of the URL ("person1") and use that to serve custom content via PHP, etc.

Essentially, I don't want the last part of the URL to change the directory that I serve the index file from.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just remove the path and have test.mysite.com. Use the location to do wildcards :)

Comment: @ScottGreenup So, if someone comes to `test.mysite.com/person1` it'll serve the same thing as someone coming to `test.mysite.com` or `test.mysite.com/person2`? And what did you mean by: "Use the location to do wildcards"

Comment: Sorry -- I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. Are you trying to have `test.mysite.com/*` all use the same index page?

Comment: @ScottGreenup Yes...that's correct.

Comment: I think you can do that with location as `location /* {...` and server_name as `server_name test.mysite.com;` -- `location` accepts regular expressions.

Comment: `server_name  test.mysite.com/person1;` is invalid. `/person1` could not be a part of server name.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I didn't think so, but how do you do it then?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here was changing `server_name` and not `location`

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name  ~^(test).*\.mysite\.com$; 
   location / {
   root  /home/testing/public_html;
   index index.html; 
 try_files                   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
   port_in_redirect off;
}
```